# Run Linux terminal on Windows

Tags: windows, linux, terminal, command-line

It is bit pain to work with Windows command prompt. I've been working with Linux and Windows. Linux terminal has more advantages than the XP command prompt, so I would like to use a Linux terminal on Windows. Does anyone know how can we do that ? I don't want to run Linux commands on Windows. But I like the features on Linux terminal so I want to use same features for the Windows command prompt or use Linux terminal on Windows.

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html

Comment: What are these "features" you like so much on Linux terminals that you wish were supported on Windows? It's difficult to recommend a terminal replacement without knowing exactly what features you are looking for!

Comment: the features I need from a terminal:

Answer (score 22):

Try [cygwin](http://cygwin.com) and bash.

Most Linux users use bash so I'm guessing that's the console you are referring to.

Comment: cygwin and bash forever!

Comment: The `rxvt` terminal is much better than the one that cygwin provides by default.  Just install the `rxvt` package to get it.

Comment: I think the poster means an alternative to cmd.exe, not the ability to run *NIX commands or bash. From the post, "I don't want to run Linux commands on Windows."

Comment: My reasoning is that if they want bash, then on Windows cygwin is probably the easiest way to do so.

Comment: Cygwin rocks :)!!

Comment: > I don't want to run Linux commands on Windows. But I like the features on Linux terminal so I want to use same features for the Windows command prompt or use Linux terminal on Windows.
<br/><br/>
Good answer, but I think the (poorly worded) question is about getting a more full-featured Windows command prompt window. It's not clear which features the OP is looking for, though.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry for the self-promotion, I'm the author of another Console Emulator, not mentioned here.

[ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) is opensource console emulator with tabs, which represents multiple consoles and simple GUI applications as one customizable GUI window.

Initially, the program was designed to work with [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/) (my favorite shell replacement - file and archive management, command history and completion, powerful editor). But ConEmu can be used with any other console application or simple GUI tools (like PuTTY for example). ConEmu is a live project, open to suggestions.

A brief excerpt from the long list of options:

- Latest versions of ConEmu may set up itself as [default terminal for Windows](https://superuser.com/a/509710/139371)
- [Split-screen](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/SplitScreen) supported
- User friendly text and block selection (from keyboard or mouse), copy, paste, text search in console
- Use any font installed in the system, or copied to a folder of the program (ttf, otf, fon, bdf)
- Run selected tabs as Administrator (Vista+) or as selected user, [csudo](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/csudo) command for new tabs
- Windows 7 Jump lists and Progress on taskbar
- Integration with [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) (useful in 64bit systems to run DOS applications)
- Smooth resize, maximized and fullscreen window modes
- Scrollbar initially hidden, may be revealed by mouseover or checkbox in settings
- Optional settings (e.g. pallette) for selected applications
- ANSI X3.64 and Xterm 256 color

Answer (score 10):

> [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) is a Windows console window enhancement.

Console[2] still uses the [Win32 console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_console) interface provided by Windows, but provides a wrapper around it with more features.  `cmd.exe` is used as the default shell but it's configurable.

---

> [Mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) is a [terminal emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) for [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and Cygwin derivatives such as [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS).

Using mintty is very much like using PuTTY to ssh into your own Cygwin installation, except without the ssh.  It hooks into Cygwin's terminal emulation to provide a faithful UNIX terminal interface.  However, this makes it unusable for programs expecting a Win32 console.

Answer (score 3):

You may try [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419). And if you know .NET you can write some really advanced scripts.