# How to change the default terminal emulator on Windows (cmd)?

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal-emulator

Is it possible to change the default terminal emulator on Windows (7 and 8 in particular) from Console to, for example, Console2 or ConEmu? In essence, I want all command line tools, whether launched by double clicking, from "Run" or by other processes to use the custom terminal.

This is a trivial matter on Linux, is it even possible on Windows?

It would be especially helpful if this could be done via a script.

Comment: s/terminal emulator/shell?  (cmd.exe is not a terminal emulator, it is a shell.)

Comment: As I understand it, both the the shell and the terminal emulator share the name. If it's not the case, I have no idea how the actual terminal emulator window is called.

Comment: Hey, it is called "console" ;) Hennes is absolutely right, for example, when you Win+R "powershell" - it will be started in the same terminal as "cm.exe"

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**Default terminal**

You may set up **[ConEmu](http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html)** as default terminal for cmd.exe, tcc.exe, powershell.exe or any other console application. In fact, you choose *from* what application you need to run *any* console application, even from Visual Studio for debugging your console applications.

[image: ConEmu's Default Terminal set up]

Just turn on checkbox, point applications from you like to start console tools (for example `explorer.exe|totalcmd.exe|wdexpress.exe`) and voila. You may press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> type `ipconfig /all` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You may even start your console application in Visual Studio debugger. New console will starts attached to the new ConEmu tab. You may also doubleclick on some executable in the Explorer window.

You may find more information about the feature in the project wiki: [DefaultTerminal](http://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html).

**Alternative**

Also, there is an alternative **less preferable** way to auto run ConEmu on cmd.exe and tcc.exe startup. Just press "Register ConEmu autorun" in Settings -> ComSpec.

Comment: Thank you, although I am looking for a more general solution! Also, thank you for your work on ConEmu, it's amazing!

Comment: "General" solution is impossible in Windows.

Comment: Though so, thank you! Too bad I can not mark the comment as the accepted answer.

Comment: Answer updated, new build arrives.

Comment: This is an amazing program. I was all happy with Consol2. Till I found this. This takes the whole think to a whole new level. Thank you man. It makes me wonder how I never heard of it.

Comment: Everything perfect, but there is a mistake in screenshot. There should be `explorer.exe|vcexpress.exe` instead of `explorer.exe, vcexpress.exe`. Thanks for this tool, it's amazing ;)

Comment: Is it possible to start up as Admin?

Comment: @JeremyHolt start what? Thought, you need to use "as admin" feature from where you try to start it. And I think, may be you need to ask another Q. with description of your use case.

Comment: @Maximus with the above option, I am able to get win+r ipconfig and .exe in win exp run in conemu. But is doesn't work when I run my console app from Visual Studio. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you add your visual studio executable?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with console projects you wish to debug in Visual Studio, still loads regular cmd ;(

Comment: Didnt work. Win+R -> "ipconfig /all" - brings old cmd window that disappears right away

Answer (score 4):

In order to change the default shell to anything, you have to change the `ComSpec` environmental variable.

On Windows 7, you Right click `My Computer`→`Properties`→`Advanced system settings` (on the left pane). Go down to the bottom and select `Environment Variables...`. Change the `ComSpec` to whatever shell application you want.

The default value is `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`.

For PowerShell it is `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.

[image: System properties window]

[image: Environment Variables window]

Comment: This answer is even better, because it doesn't imply dependence on 3rd party apps.

Comment: This answer is about changing the shell. What program gets used to interact with the shell is a different matter. You can run cmd or powershell or git bash in any console program you like, eg. conEmu.