# Modify "Open command window here" context menu call

Tags: windows-registry, cmd.exe, conemu, cmder

I've recently started using [cmder](http://bliker.github.io/cmder/) instead of Window's default cmd prompt and I'm really loving it. I'm at the point now where I want to replace all instances of *cmd.exe* being launched with *cmder.exe* being launched instead.

For the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Rightclick context menu in folders, how can I set the "Open command window here" to launch *cmder*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe next registry key: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd`; exporting it from `regedit` gives next output:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

Try next changes in the exported file and then import it (i.e. `Merge` from right-click context menu) with elevated privileges (it will **add** `Open CMDER here` functionality to your file explorer, supposing right path to `cmder.exe` in the last line); if you want to **replace** the `Open command window here` functionality, then change the last line only:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmder]
@="Open CMDER here"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmder\command]
;;; @="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
@="cmd.exe /s /d /c pushd \"%V\"&start \"\" cmder.exe"
```

**Edit**

- `cmd.exe` [command line parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html):

  - `/s` Strip quote characters from the command_line;
  - `/d` Ignore registry AutoRun commands;
  - `/c` Run Command and then terminate;
  - `pushd "%V"` [Change the current directory/folder](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and store the previous folder/path for use by the POPD command;
  - `&` [Run command before and then run command after](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html);
- `start "" cmder.exe` launches your application;
- all `"` are escaped here with `\`;

  - to add full path to `cmder.exe`, e.g. `"C:\bin\cmder.exe"`, escape all `\` as well.

If last statement is the case, then use syntax as follows:

```
@="cmd.exe /s /d /c pushd \"%V\"&start \"\" \"C:\\bin\\cmder.exe\""
```

Comment: That and 3 more keys ConEmu can process internally without user required registry modifications.

Comment: In theory this makes sense to me, but the parameters it passed to cmder.exe aren't valid and I can't figure out what the correct parameters would be.

Comment: What is `@` meant here? `@="Open CMDER here"`: is it a key?

Comment: @Love `@` represents  "name" of default value (which is nameless really) in a subkey.

Comment: @JosefZ, Could you please a snapshot for `cmder`part so I can understand it better? Thanks.

Comment: @Love sorry, I don't comprehend your request. Please ask Google for `understanding windows registry`. In doubts, elaborate your own question.

Comment: @JosefZ, I meant that I need a picture like [this](https://www.flickr.com/photos/67801243@N06/26889137671/in/dateposted-public/). I created it by [the example](http://armannvg.com/2015/08/18/in-love-with-cmder/). But it is not working.

Comment: @Love `@="c:\\cmder\\cmder.exe \"%V\""` in `.reg` file should result to next entry  seen in registry editor `(Default) REG_SZ c:\cmder\cmder.exe "%V"` after merging.

Comment: @JosefZ, Thanks, now it is working. The script in the link is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try this works for me (This one is to modify "**Open command window Here"**)

Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd\command` & then change the default value to `"C:\cmder\Cmder.exe" "%V"` & Also do the same for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd\command` that is also change the default value to `"C:\cmder\Cmder.exe" "%V"`

Optionally you can also add icons

To add icons goto `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd` Make a new String Value Name it `Icon` & give its value as `"C:\cmder\Cmder.exe"` & do the same for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd\command`

[image: Instructions]

**Edited :** Changed `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\cmd` to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd` . Windows 10 have these things. I forgot about my older settings in windows 7.

Comment: Can you post a snapshot? It is not working.

Comment: The link is not working.

Comment: Sorry for that, see now screenshot has been added.

Comment: So did you override the dos command? I would prefer keep both of them. That is meant to keep both Windows command cmd and cmder.

Comment: So you want to add another context option in the right click . See this tool, I use this tool too http://www.door2windows.com/ultimate-windows-context-menu-customizer-customize-context-menu-in-windows-xp-vista-7/ & in place of command use `"C:\cmder\Cmder.exe" "%V"` & select the Icon. Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

**Context Menu Integration**

So you've experimented with Cmder a little and want to give it a shot in a more permanent home;

- Shortcut to open Cmder in a chosen folder
- Open a terminal as an Administrator
- Navigate to the directory you have placed Cmder
- Execute .\cmder.exe /REGISTER ALL If you get a message "Access Denied" ensure you are executing the command in an Administrator prompt.

source: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder

[image]

Comment: why so low. Easiest answer

Comment: I really like this solution - except it does open a new instance every time i use this, shame it can't reuse and open a new tab instead

Answer (score 0):

cmder if the ConEmu actually. So you can go two ways

1. Set up ConEmu's menu items instead of Windows standard. Go to Settings\Integration and press "Register" in "ConEmu here" group. Of course you can choose there any shell to be started.
2. ConEmu can "fully" replace standard Windows terminal using "[Default terminal](https://superuser.com/a/509710/139371)" feature. Just go to "Settings\Default term" and turn it on. So all console applications started from Explorer (even from Win+R) will be started in ConEmu.

Comment: This adds extra context menu options which I don't want, I want to edit the existing one.

Comment: Use "DefTerm" feature then.