# Change Windows default console

Tags: windows, command-line, console

I use [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files) (SourceForge warning), and I'd like to essentially replace the default command prompt with Console. If there's a global way to do this I'd be very happy, but at the very least I'd like to change the option in Explorer that opens command prompt in the current directory. I can figure out the Console flags, I'm not worried about that, but I don't know where to make the change to make it open with Console.

How can I change the Windows default console? I'm on Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64.

Comment: It's possible with ConEmu only: http://superuser.com/a/509710/139371

Comment: Do **not** rename `cmd.exe` if you don't want to break your Windows!